# Draw rectangle around text

Tags: android, text, android-canvas

I need to draw rectangle around `text` on canvas. 
Currently I am using this to calculate rectangle position:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds(getData().getText(), 0, getData().getText().length(), bounds);

data.getBoundBox().left = start.x+bounds.left;
data.getBoundBox().right = start.x+bounds.right;
data.getBoundBox().top = start.y + bounds.top;
data.getBoundBox().bottom = start.y+bounds.bottom;
```

Where start is coordinate of `text` baseline.
But i got this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29406527/Screenshot_2013-12-27-14-15-28.png

I tried things like `measureText`, but i got no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a shape drawable and set it as a background to the TextView.

This is the shape drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke 
        android:dashWidth="3dp" 
        android:dashGap="3dp" 
        android:color="#FFFFFF" 
        android:width="1dp"/>

    <padding 
        android:left="10dp" 
        android:top="10dp" 
        android:right="10dp" 
        android:bottom="10dp"/>

    <corners 
        android:radius="4dp" />

</shape>
```

And this is how you set it as a background:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    />
```

Comment: This might be the initial intention, but maybe he wishes to really play with the canvas?

Comment: Yes, I need to draw it programatically. Plus, now i find out, that getTextBounds, does not include underline, if i have some.:(